# Getting SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 47732

Tags: http

I am getting this error when testing my Flutter application on a real device: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 47732

But it works fine on a emulator.
Only getting this error on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app communicating with a local hosted website? 10.0.2.2 is a request to the 127.0.0.1 on your development machine. Your real device might not have the permissions to access this locally hosted website.